# Working With Media Queries In Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have searched everywhere and the problem might be that what I am looking for does not exist.

I am constantly chasing down media queries when working updating websites. Is there a way to show all media queries for an element?

I know I can change the emulator to a certain device but it does not show me the media queries for that element based on that device size?

I was thinking maybe there is a setting for this but I cannot find it.

How can I easily see all media queries effecting an element I am working with in the DOM using Google Chrome Tools?

[image]

Comment: Do you have last version of chrome?

Comment: I have latest yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, just follow this steps:

1- Open chrome **web tools**,

2- Press the **emulator icon**,

3- Press the Option button `⋮` in the **very top-right** of the page (in the black bar under the bookmarks bar),

4- Press "**Show media queries**",

5- There you can see all media breakpoints,

6- **Right-click** on the breakpoints that you want and press "**Reveal in source code**" to see the CSS.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports#media-queries

For a Better explaination:
[image: How see all media queries chrome]

Comment: I saw that online. I dont have that option

Comment: I updated my question with a pic. But yes your right that information was online which is why I am asking the question on here. Because it seems to not be accurate. Do you have this option in your dev tools?

Comment: Omg your right I didnt see the other menu. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey I see the color bars show now and they are where each query is at but it doesnt show the actual css query in the dom. How do I make it show me all the queries for that element in the inspector?

Comment: Right-click on the breakpoints that you want and press "Reveal in source code"

Comment: Ahh Perfect that is exactly what I needed.